# Reverse psudo random number generating

Tags: probability-theory, algorithms, cryptography

I'm trying to figure out a formula that can "reverse" or "crack a pseudoRNG, my goal is to be able to plug in the past results of the the pseudoRNG and reverse calculate it in order to figure out the seed number or code so that I can plug it back into the rng and be able to accurately predict the next sequence it will generate, idk if this is even possible or if anything like this even exists but its a concept I need help on.

Comment: you need to make assumptions about how the pseudo random number generator is working - if it was one of the old VB ones, you could have a table of all random values in the cycle of numbers it produces, then look and find that sequence of (even just I think) two numbers, then have the 'seed' value that that produces tabulated

Comment: If you are able to conveniently reverse engineer your PRNG, get a better one.

Comment: Its not going to be conveniant in the least bit nor will it be easy but anything done on a computer cant possably be 100% genuinly random beacuse computers dont work in that way hence the use of the term pseudo,  although nowdays knowledge of math and computers makes it look more random it is not really more random just more complicated

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of pseudorandom numbers is that this is *impossible*; if they were easy to predict, then they wouldn't be properly random. For some specific types of p-random number generators we know how to do this -- which in fact makes them *bad* p-random number generators, and as a result we usually do not use them anymore.

Comment: As you say, the old BASIC pseudo randoms were just based on  a mathematical calculation that the modulus was taken of - then the next number was that number dropped into the same formula.  That looked random, but wasn't.  For that reason, pseudo randoms for encryption also exist - now are they always good enough?  Well I've heard that called into question!  Manuals still tell us not to use basic RND functions for cryptography, I've seen them used (wrongly) to make GUIDS - the limited range of seeds means that randomness is not sufficient

Comment: So there is no way to plug every past value generated into a formula and calculate it to figue out the exact seed in the more modern rng

Comment: There *shouldn't* be a way; I don't want to go on the record as saying it's literally impossible. I highly doubt it'd be easy, though. And it's certainly not possible without having any information about which PRNG we are talking about.

Comment: Alright is there any possable way you can think of to start going about it?

Comment: I'm not so sure it is impossible for the pseudo random generators that are tagged as NOT sufficient for encryption and security.  You might be able to find something using a reverse engineering tool such as reflector or ISPY, and some languages might even publish their random number algorithms.  do you know a lot about programming?

Comment: I know enough to get me by

Comment: Impossible is a strong word, it should not be possible to do it *efficiently*, i.e. in polynomial time. In exponential time, the problem is always solvable just by trying all possible seed values.

Comment: I 'cracked' the 1999 version in 1 second processing, it has a weedy sequence of 16million - people still use VB6.  Note that the original RNDs were for monte-carlo simulations, games etc - when encryption came along, some people started to beef up the routines (but it doesn't mean they get used correctly) the .net implementation is in fact wrong!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example from Visual Studio 2008 which I still use, it took my PC about 1 second to generate all the possible pseudo randoms, I can use the list to find the next pseudo random - note that I went back to the old VB6 (1999) pseudo random number generator, not now available in the latest versions of Visual Studio

As I say, ISpy or reflector might even show you the calculations behind various calculations - I'm sure no two generators will be guaranteed to be alike.  Some generators build up random entropy pots from 'random' system events (an example is a mouse move event, the time, size, and direction of a mouse move can be stored to provide random input to a proper random number generator)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim pseuds As New List(Of Single)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 17000000

        pseuds.Add(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Rnd)

    Next

    Dim op As Single = Rnd()

    Dim key As Integer = pseuds.FindIndex(Function(x) CBool(x = op))

    Dim NextP As Single = pseuds(key + 1)

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("next pseud = {0} : predicted = {1}", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Rnd, NextP))

End Sub
```

from the .net help on random number generator

Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers. The chosen numbers are not completely random because a mathematical algorithm is used to select them, but they are sufficiently random for practical purposes. The current implementation of the Random class is based on a modified version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm. For more information, see D. E. Knuth. The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms. Addison-Wesley, Reading, MA, third edition, 1997.

Comment: here's something interesting, the intended .net algorithm has an intended length of 2^55 (a 16 digit number) - they got it wrong though, Microsoft knows and can't fix it - in case it breaks existing software - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug